# How should I go about determining whether or not this series converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$h_n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[\sum_{m=0}^{n}\frac{1}{2^m}{}]$

I know that $h_n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{2^0}+\frac{1}{2^1}+...+\frac{1}{2^n})$, but I'm not really sure where this is going.
Could someone at least hint towards what convergence test I should use?
Thanks

Comment: Each term of the outer sum exceeds $1$.

Comment: Ah.So it definitely diverges, by the Divergence Test, then?

Comment: Yes, indeed.${}$

Comment: Or just, you know, common sense... ($h_n\geq n$)

Comment: Yeah, but we have to write things rigourously in our course.

Comment: How would I show that $\sum_{m=0}^{n}\frac{1}{2^m}>1$?
I know that $\sum_{m=0}^{n}\frac{1}{2^m}=2[1-({\frac{1}{2}})^{n+1}]$, but, then, how would I rigourously show that this is $>1$ for all $n$?

Comment: All the terms are positive, so it's larger than its first term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Add $\dfrac1{2^n}$ to the general term, and see what happens. :-)